# How to find which `method` is from which `namespace` in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, namespaces

I was doing a code review and I wanted to know that if there is a way to find out which all methods are being used in a program that belong to a particular namespace. For example, in the image below:

[image]

you can see the `.NET Framework Class Library` namespaces that are being declared in this particular scenario.

My question is: How can I find out where a particular method of a particular namespace is being used in the program. In the image below:

[image]

you can see that when I hover on `ConfigurationManager`, it tells me that it belongs to the `System.Configuration` namespace.

I wanted to know if there are way to find a list of all methods that belong to a particular namespace in a `.cs` file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remark the `using` statement and check the errors list? I'm guessing resharper can give you this information but I don't have a wroking copy of it so I can't check.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Doing the error list will take a lot of manual labor. I will check out the `resharper` as your suggested. Thanks

Comment: Just press `F12` when the cursor is on a Method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have ReSharper, you can put the cursor on the word "using" in the using statement, and then right-click and "Find Usages". This will show all usages of methods, classes etc in the namespace, as you require. Make sure the cursor is on "using" - if it's on the namespace name itself, then it will find all of the using statements for that namespace instead.

Answer (score 0):

for my experience and if i understand you correctly,

To find where a method is being used, u can right click on the method and click "Find all References" [Like this](http://prntscr.com/og71a3)

And to know what methods are available in a cs, i only know [this way](http://prntscr.com/og72xk)